# PHP - wait a couple of seconds before continuing?

Tags: php, sleep

I've set up a HTML form and I'm using PHP to verify that everything is good before displaying a message on the webpage. I then want to redirect the user back to the home page after a couple of seconds.

Problem is, I can't find a way to wait 5 seconds or so and then do the redirect. The sleep function simply waits 5 seconds and then displays the message/redirects at the same time. Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks!

```
<?php
    if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    echo 'Success! You will not be able to log in until an administrator approves your account.';
    sleep(5);
    $url = 'index.html';
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';  
}
?>
```

Comment: Use meta refresh with a value of 5, not 0, and remove the `sleep`.

Comment: Ouch. I cringed at sleeping after echoing. You want to do your *validation* and then return success, not do *nothing*

Comment: Note that if the above *would* work, you'd effectively make your web server load increase a lot. (Not sure if/how PHP uses workers, but it surely would make something on the server be busy for 5 seconds, probably blocking other requests. A self-inflicted DoS if you will!)

Comment: I'm with @Arjan. Don't do this

Answer (score 5):

For a practical (works across the board AFAIK) but *not standardized* solution, use the `Refresh` HTTP header:

```
header('Refresh: 5; url=http://yoursite.com/index.html');
```

Otherwise, you can achieve the effect with a `<meta>` tag but without involving `sleep()`:

```
// This goes inside <head>, so obviously *before* the "success" message!
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="5; URL='.$url.'">';
```

Comment: That's the technical correct answer on a CRAP question. I would advice nobody to do this

Comment: "How can I start an atomic bomb" ... Jon: "please press the red button. And , but this is not standardized, you can also press the blue button"

Comment: think for yourself. why should a script sleep for 5 seconds in this case? And if you (for whatever reason) come to the answer that sleepiness is ok, why 5sec and not 4 or 6?. sleep() isn't helpful in any case here. As it isn't in most cases

Comment: Update: You used an HTTP header or `<meta>` tags for the solution. That's better than the original sleep attempt! Of course. But it remains the fact that "'I've set up a HTML form and I'm using PHP to verify that everything is good before displaying a message on the webpage'" is BAD design. What is 'good' after 5 seconds waiting?

Comment: @hek2mgl: The essence of the question is "I can't find a way to wait 5 seconds or so and then do the redirect". There are quite a number of websites that do this, as in "you have logged in, redirecting...". Not necessary perhaps, but what exactly is the bad design?

Comment: I'm already answered this: 'What is 'good' after 5 seconds?' .. How many CPU cycles of the (assumed apache) process has gone after 5 seconds? What is '5 seconds' worth? Is it reliable to wait 5 seconds? Can this be exploited? .... ---> CRAP!

Answer (score 2):

This should be done on the client side using javascript for example.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Try googling things like javascript redirect ;)
http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php

Answer (score 1):

That is because the output is not sent to the browser sequentially. PHP sends out the output mostly in one go, after the script has terminated.

Instead use this meta-tag for waiting in html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; URL=/blah;">
```

Note that `<meta>` tags always should be put inside `<head>`.

Note that the browser can always choose to ignore redirects. And, although that is my personal opinion, redirects like this suck. Rather display a notice flash message at the top of the next pageload imho.

Answer (score 0):

The way you do such redirections is javascript

Make a small javascript function like

```
function delayer() {
    window.location = "http://example.com"
}
```

and add it with

```
onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS_TO_WAIT)"
```

inside your html body tag

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I worked up to redirect. Seems to work fine and thought I would share.

```
DelayTime(15); 

echo "<script>window.top.location.reload();</script>";
```

The DelayTime Function:

```
function DelayTime($secs){
      $now = time();
      while($now < ($now + $sec)){ 
        $now = time();
        if($now >= ($now + $sec)){ break; }
      }
      return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    echo 'Success! You will not be able to log in until an administrator approves your account.';
    sleep(5);
    $url = 'index.html';
    header("location: ".$url);  
}
?>
```

if it don't work need to use javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("window.location = 'index.html'", 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: PHP uses a buffer, so eveything will be displayed at the same time at the end of the script.

And your solution would display an error for headers (they are set after an output, which PHP doesn't like very much...)